# Animação do botão não acontece

Tags: jquery, html, css

Quando eu clicasse no botão era pra ele ir pra esquerda por 400ms porém quando eu clico ele vai direto sem a animação, ele "pula" direto pro lugar final sem passar pelo resto.

#### CSS:

```
#icone-menu.icone-menu-animacao{
    left: -10px;
    position: relative;

}
```

#### JS com JQuery:

```
$("#btn-menu").on("click", function(){
        $('#icone-menu').toggleClass('icone-menu-animacao', 400);
    });
```

#### HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="btn-menu">
<img src="img/menu55.png" id="icone-menu">
</a>
```

#### Novo CSS:

```
#icone-menu{
    position: block;
     left:0;
     transition: 0.2s;   
}
#icone-menu.icone-menu-animacao{
    left: -10px;
    position: relative;
    transition: 0.2s;
}
```

Comment: se a resposta estiver certa, por favor marca-a como certa :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As transições CSS acontecem devido a propriedade `transition`, sem ela as trocas de propriedades dos elementos irão acontecer de forma "brusca". Para fazer qualquer troca (desde que a transition afete estes) de elementos você pode usar essa propriedade. Ela controla o tempo de transição, o tipo de transição e diversas outras coisas.

Dessa forma, para fazer um elemento ter uma animação, você simplesmente pode usar o jQuery para colocar (ou tirar) uma classe que irá mudar as propriedades desse elemento, dai em diante, a `transition` irá animar essa troca. Exemplo:

```js
$('#block').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('mover');
});
```

```css
#block {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:blue;
    position:relative;
    left:0;
    transition:left .5s linear;
}

#block.mover {
    left:150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="block"></div>
```

E um detalhe, você utilizou um segundo parâmetro no comando `toggleClass` em sua pergunta. Isso não está errado, porém esse segundo parâmetro só funciona se estiver a utilizar o jQuery UI.

Comment: Rafael me diz uma coisa, eu tenho um id assim `#id{display:none;opacity:0;transition: all 1s linear;}` e chamo o toggle `#id.toggle{display:block;opacity:1;}`, mas ele fica sem animação nenhuma. Eu acho que é por causa do `display`. Tem algo que eu possa fazer?

Comment: Isso acontece porque a transition não afeta a propriedade `display`, o ideal seria utilizara apenas a propriedade `opacity`: http://jsfiddle.net/th6w20us/  
Existem alguns artigos que cuidam desse assunto: http://www.impressivewebs.com/animate-display-block-none/

Comment: Uma solução rápida e fácil é usar a função `fadeToggle`, ela ja cuida disso tudo fazendo seu elemento aparecer e sumir do jeito que você quer. Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/th6w20us/1/

Answer (score 2):

O seu CSS tem que ter `transition` e um "default state", está aqui um exemplo em [jsFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/fwy0om7g/1/);
Mais, o `,400` na linha `$('#icone-menu').toggleClass('icone-menu-animacao', 400);` não é necessário uma vez que o `toggleClass` [só leva um argumento](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

Comment: mas me diga, como fazer pra ele voltar com a animação também? Poque ele esta voltando direto..

Comment: @AndreyHartung para voltar com animação também, você altera o css do "default state" para ter posição relativa e transition [assim](http://jsfiddle.net/fwy0om7g/2/)

Comment: 2 coisas, 1o pq eu não consigo te referenciar no inicio na mensagem? eu coloco `@MoshMage` e some ¬¬ 2o eu editei ali com o CSS que ta agora e eu tirei o 400 mas a animação de volta ainda n está acontecendo...

Comment: @AndreyHartung quanto ao primeiro, eu não sei x)    
Quanto ao segundo, faz um jsfiddle e põe o link aqui para ver o que se passa :)

Comment: consegui fazer tudo que eu queria, eu reescrevi 96% do funcionamento das animações kkkkkkkkkkk

Comment: Boa @AndreyHartung ! :) só fiquei foi um bocado triste por a minha não ser a resposta aceite como 'certa' quando ambas as respostas estão (essencialmente) iguais :P

Comment: Eu marquei a resposta dele como certa, porque apesar das duas serem muito parecidas a dele é um pouco melhor tratada. Tanto que a sua na volta o menu bugava e ele nos comentários me ajudou a tratar isso e postou até alguns links de artigos. Mas agradeço muito sua ajuda, eu comecei a arrumar a minha bagunça aqui com a sua ajuda!